# How to Create customized ubuntu server 18.04 LTS ISO file?

Tags: file, iso, ubuntu-server, customizing

I want to know how to customize the iso content after mounting the ubuntu server iso file. For example, I would like to customize the Linux kernel Real-time Patch, three servers, and a GUI installation with ISO files.

Please let me know detail about customizing iso file.

Thanks.